# What does *int mean?

Tags: c, parsing, pointers, syntax

I know what a pointer is, but during some coding exercises i had a typo and instead of `int*` used `*int`.

I understand it's wrong, but does it mean something in C (e.g syntactically valid)?
is it static semantics ?
is it just undefined?

Couldn't figure it out with the compiler warnings.

Edit: (relevant compiler warnings)

```
void input(*int ,*int );
```

:10: error: expected primary-expression before "int"
:10: error: expected primary-expression before "int"
:10: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression

Comment: Please share the compiler warnings.

Comment: It's going to depend on the context.  Post the code.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that's invalid syntax.

Comment: Folks! Cut Dagoth some slack please! Questions like this are the beginning of C parsing wisdom.

Comment: Compiler *warnings*? I'd expect any code that uses `*int` to result in a syntax error message. Generally a "warning" is explicitly labeled as a warning, and doesn't cause the compilation to fail.

Comment: @Jens: "is this syntax I made up that generated a syntax error in the compiler syntactically valid?" doesn't seem like the beginning of anything except a Not a Real Question closure.

Comment: *sigh* ...sometimes it's almost not worth it.

Comment: @Jens: No, they're not.  Randomly stringing tokens together and asking someone what they mean doesn't imply any effort or desire to learn anything.

Comment: @Woblee For me it falls into the kind of questions along "If I mistype this, will this maybe quietly compile and do something different?" - A little imagination and politeness goes a long way. Assume good faith.

Comment: @Jens: Thing is, that question can easily be answered for oneself by typing it into a file and trying to compile it.  If it doesn't compile *but should*, or compiles *but shouldn't*, those are useful questions.  "Does this garbage, that i *know* is garbage (note the "I understand it's wrong..." above), mean something?"  Not so much.

Comment: @DagothUlen If you mistype something and that compiles, _then_ you have a question. If you mistype, and the compiler says "Uh, what, that doesn't make sense?", that's not a question. Except perhaps "Can anybody explain this compiler message to me? I don't understand how this typo [...] leads to that message [...]", that would be a valid question [possibly even intriguing, compiler errors can be arcane].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's a syntax error. It can't be part of a multiplication since there cannot be an identifier with the name of a keyword.

The only way to make this a valid part of a C program is

- as part of a string literal
- as part of a multibyte character constant
- as part of a comment
- when `int` is a macro expanding to something else that makes it valid
- within an `#ifdef`'ed out code segment
- something else I forgot

Comment: You could make it part of an unused macro: `#define UNUSED39898439854389 *int`

Comment: @Chris +1 Righto! This is fun.